# High cost on Azure Function webjobs storage for Event Hub checkpoints

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

We want to use an Azure Function (AF) to pull data (15k msg/min & 35 Mb/min) from an Event Hub (EH) and store it in Azure Synapse (formerly Data Warehouse). For EH input, the AF uses a Storage Account to store the most recent checkpoints of every EH partition (32 partitions). For some reason the cost of this storage is by far exceeding the cost of the AF itself.

The [cost analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXP4I.png) by meter for one day shows, that it´s the high count of read, write & other operations, which cause these high costs. Also you can see, that the storage costs are around 40x higher than the Function itself.

The interesting thing is we already successfully use a similar setup with an EH being input for an AF, where the storage costs are roughly the same than the AF itself, despite the EH streaming the same data (messages & volume) and also being configured with 32 partitions.

[This stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49870731/expensive-use-of-storage-account-from-azure-functions?rq=1) seemed to deal with the same issue, but there was no real solution apart from,

> "I believe creating a new function and deploying the code to that has fixed the problem."

What are we missing? Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had the same issue.

- Use General Purpose V1 storage accounts instead of V2 or blob storage. For one client, we got the storage account costs down from about 3000€ per month to about 100€, just by using V1.
- Do less checkpointing. Don't checkpoint after every single message. You can control that by increasing the setting `batchCheckpointFrequency` for EventHub triggers. The only downside is that you might reprocess a couple of messages in case your function goes down unexpectedly.

Comment: Thx, I´m gonna try this. Will V1 storage be deprecated any time soon? Is V1 so much cheaper, or is the cause still unclear?

Comment: I don't think V1 storage will be deprecated in the next 2 years, but that is just a guess by me. Given that you can still create many of the classic non-ARM resources, it is probably much more than that. V1 storage is massively more cheap, especially for these small transactions like checkpointing. You can check https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?service=storage

Comment: Hey, thx again for your input. First tests do confirm the massively lower cost in v1 storage. Next to the many write operations an Azure Function executes, while storing the Event Hub checkpoints, we also have the same issue while writing actual data into Blob via an AF. This is supposed to be our long term data storage for a data platform we are working on. But we don´t have a good feeling by using storage v1 now, since it´s marked as legacy. How can Microsoft introduce storage v2 and make write operations a whopping 100x more expensive? With the data of one day for us this is 3$ vs. 300$/day

Comment: No idea really what they thought with that. You could evaluate the V2 cold tier for your data, but you need to have massive amounts of stored data before that really saves costs. With regards to the original question: I am glad that my solution helped you. I would appreciate it if you marked the answer as accepted by clicking the check mark. This helps keep the focus on older questions which still don't have answers.

Comment: Personally, I go with V1, the only downside is the storage keeps growing as I can't get them to delete automatically (which is easy in V2). This means it gets more expensive quite slowly, but also a bit slower. So what I do is just trash it every few months and start from scratch.

Comment: Can't you use a dedicated Storage Account with V2 that you use for your cistom blobs?