# Unexpected costs in Azure Function & Storage

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

Now, I'm using Azure Functions & Azure Storage.
Recently, while checking the cost of resources, I found out that there was an unexpected cost in Storage.
The following image shows the cost list for the storage account. (Units: Japanese yen.)
You can see that the write operation of file sharing incurs a cost.

[image: cost list]

Checking the metrics of File sharing, we see that a transaction has occurred.

[image: metrics]

However, since there is no access to File sharing in the code, and the function is executed only a few times a day, I don't know why this transaction is occurring.
Does anyone know of a way to mitigate this cost?

The following is an summary of Fucntions.

- Runtime: Node 14
- Function extension version: 3
- Number of functions:

  - HTTP trigger: 6 (Executes about 3 times a day.)
  - Time trigger: 1 (Every four hours.)
- Plan: pay-as-you-go

host.json:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "never",
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "None"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  }
}
```

I referred to the related article, but could not solve the problem.

- https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/832
- https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1307
- [Expensive use of storage account from Azure Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49870731/expensive-use-of-storage-account-from-azure-functions)

Comment: Raise a azure support ticket and ask for explanation on this

Comment: Pricing questions are off-topic, unfortunately. That said: what time period is your billing report? 11 Yen is around ~11 cents, and there might not be much you can do to mitigate this. I would suggest looking at storage billing, and how low-level transactions (API calls) are billed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure functions use Azure Storage to manage keys/run state/store code. This is outlined here: [Storage Considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/storage-considerations)

This is likely the cost associated with these operations which can not be mitigated.